# Analysis of a dataset and tool to get the incidence of an event

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dataset, mathematical-statistics

I have a dataset and I want to do statistical analysis:

```
session    day     type   entity   name           RunningTime  PLACE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      29/09/10   1      Tera     NikolaT        24:33        unknown
 2      14/12/10   1      Vera     EmmanuelF      22:13        Aldebaran
 3      29/01/11   1      Eon      Eon            null         all    
 4      01/03/10   1      NA       DSG            12:25        earth
 5      02/11/10   1      Ardan    alvaroR        43:56        Aldebaran
```

for instance I want to get the probability distribution of the incidence of an event, ocurrence of sessions....,

I was planing first to sort by day and then getting $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for each month and then by year, but

what is the best approach to get valuable information from this dataset?
what statistical analysis can be done in a dataset like this?
what tool instead of matlab or R can I use, that is online?

Comment: We need more information on why you are interested in this to be able to give any advice on what analysis to do.  Also it isn't clear what you mean by an "event", and certainly not what might be meant by the probability distribution of the incident of event.  And occurence of sessions - what do you need to know?  Is the task one of summarising, presenting, or inference to some population or model?

Comment: suppose I know that some sessions occur at certain date, I want to find patters, I would like to represent a model and the time invested in the sessions, what analysis would help to discover some information like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information here to give you a very good answer but here are some pointers.

First - clarify what you want to know - it sounds very vague at this point.  What decisions need evidence to inform them?  What questions can you answer that will help those decisions?  How can you refine those questions into something you can confront with data?  What statistical model will allow tests that facilitate that confrontation?

Second - when you get into analysis, start with graphics, not thinking about which statistical tests to use.

Draw a plot with a point for each session, date on the horizontal axis, length of session on the vertical axis, location represented by shape or colour, and entity name represented by colour or shape (if there is more than one session per entity; otherwise don't bother).

Add some smoothed lines to that plot to see if there are trends over time or if the lines have different slopes or general heights on the vertical axis.

Draw a boxplot of the session times with different boxes and/or facets for location and month.  Draw some density line plots of similar categorisations.

Definitely statistical tests can be done on this sort of data - you can see for example if there is evidence that the length of sessions is systematically growing over time (this requires some complex time series analysis) or between groups.  You could produce a model to predice total session time per day, or average length of sessions at different locations, or anything else that is of interest and is observed.  More information needed to help here.

The ideal tool for this is the ggplot2 package within R, sorry I don't have recommendations of a free tool available online other than R.

Comment: Could you please point out some code to graph what you described?.  Your answer is really useful as I didn't know where to start.  I was thinking to use   
 `
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- read.table( "dta.txt" , header=T, sep='\t', comment.char='-', quote='' )
p + geom_point( aes( x=day, y=RunningTime, colour=significant) )
dev.new()
tmp <- p + geom_histogram( aes( x=day ) )
print( tmp )`